Kanzen Master N3 Grammar Questions
There is a question in Kanzen Master's N3 gramar book, 3 and 4 練習, that I'm confused by:
Question 6: ( ) くらいなら、今の生活レベルでがまんしよう。
a. いい仕事がない　　b。仕事が欲しい　　c。きつい仕事をする
My original thought was that the answer was a, but the answer is c. I thought that inserting a would make the sentence mean something along the lines of "Since/if there is no good work available, you should persevere with your current life."
What am I misunderstanding about option c?

The sentences before and after くらいなら should be things that the narrator can personally do, with the action before くらいなら being the least desirable option for the narrator. For example:
タバコをやめるくらいなら、死んだほうがマシだ。 (correct usage)
"I'd rather die than quit smoking."
Both quiting smoking and (continuing to smoke and) dying are the actions the narrator can choose. In this case, "タバコをやめる"(quitting smoking) is the least desirable choice for the narrator.
雨が降るくらいなら、傘を持っていこう。 (incorrect usage)
"I'd rather take an umbrella if it's going to rain."
White the English sentence makes sense, in Japanese, this usage is odd because "雨が降る"(it rains) is not what the narrator can control --  it's something the weather does.
雨に濡れるくらいなら、傘を持っていこう。(correct usage)
"I'd rather take an umbrella than get wet in the rain."
This is correct because "雨に濡れる"(getting wet in the rain) is an action the narrator can take, and it is the least desirable option.
Similarly, "いい仕事がない"(there is no good job) is not the narrator can control -- it depends on the companies offering jobs.
"仕事がほしい"(I want a job) can be something the narrator can do, but it does not sound like the least desirable choice.
"きつい仕事をする"(to do hard work), on the other hand, is what the narrator can choose and it can be seen as the least desirable option. Therefore, the correct answer is C: "きつい仕事をする."
